# Why does updating only some rows delete the rest of the rows in the column?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-update

I have a table with 100 rows, indexed 1-100. I have another table with 50 rows, indexed 1-50. I want to take the rows in the 50 row table and update the values at the corresponding index in the 100 row table:

```
UPDATE t100 SET text = (SELECT text FROM t50 WHERE t50.id = t100.id)
```

It works, but it turns rows 51-100 to `NULL` in the 100 row table. I just wanted to keep that data there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have a WHERE condition, so it will update all rows. Since you don't have data to put in all rows, the rest will be set to NULL.

Comment: If you want help finding a more general solution, you may want to add which RDBMS (oracle/mysql/sql server/...) you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating all entries of `t100` regardless of whether there is a corresponding entry in `t50`. What you should be doing is:

```
UPDATE t100 SET text = (SELECT text FROM t50 WHERE t50.id = t100.id)
WHERE t100.id IN (SELECT id FROM t50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you update every row in t100.

Add the following to the end of your query

```
Where t100.id <=50
```

Comment: This might be valid in the current scenario, but it doesn't generalize well, whereas using `WHERE t100.id IN (SELECT id FROM t50)` works regardless of which set of rows in t100 match the rows in t50.

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables like this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.text = t2.text
FROM t100 AS t1
INNER JOIN t50 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```